# IntelliJ idea: kotlinx-cli not resolved in code, though included in the project

Tags: kotlin, maven, intellij-idea

To make it clean I created in IntelliJ a new project named TestCLI, build system IntelliJ.
Included kotlinx-cli-0.3.5 (from Maven) in project libraries and in the module.
The library appears in External Libraries, class  ArgParser is listed among others, however the library is not recognised in the code

import kotlinx.cli.*  gives error 'Unresolved reference kotlinx'
also Kotlin: Unresolved reference: ArgParser  for class kotlinx.cli.ArgParser (or just 'ArgParser')

Tried '**Invalidate Cache and Restart**' numerous times even with all options checked - didn't help.

[image: Project structure: libraries] Project structure: libraries

[image: Project structure: Dependencies] Project structure: Dependencies

[image: .iml file].iml file

[image: Project, code and error] Project, code and error

Answer (score 1):

I replaced kotlinx-cli.0.3.5 with  kotlinx-cli-jvm.0.3.5 and it started working. I have no idea though, what is the reason of having two libraries.